# Text scrolling (Marquee) in QLabel

Tags: qt, text, scroll, label, marquee

I'm studying [WidgetMarqueeLabel](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1132075/) class:

```
#include "WidgetMarqueeLabel.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>

WidgetMarqueeLabel::WidgetMarqueeLabel(QWidget *parent)//*parent)
{   
        px = 0;
        py = 10;
        speed = 1;
        direction = RightToLeft;
        connect(&timer3, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(refreshLabel()));
        timer3.start(10);
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::refreshLabel()
{
    repaint();  
}

WidgetMarqueeLabel::~WidgetMarqueeLabel()
{}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::show()
{   
    QLabel::show();
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment al)
{
    m_align = al;
    updateCoordinates();
    QLabel::setAlignment(al);
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *evt)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    if(direction==RightToLeft)
    {
        px -= speed;
        if(px <= (-textLength))
            px = width();
    }
    else
    {
        px += speed;
        if(px >= width())
            px = - textLength;
    }
        p.drawText(px, py+fontPointSize, text());
    p.translate(px,0);
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt)
{   
    updateCoordinates();
    QLabel::resizeEvent(evt);
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::updateCoordinates()
{
    switch(m_align)
    {
        case Qt::AlignTop:
            py = 10;
            break;
        case Qt::AlignBottom:
                        py = height()-10;
            break;
        case Qt::AlignVCenter:
            py = height()/2;
            break;
    }
    fontPointSize = font().pointSize()/2;
    textLength = fontMetrics().width(text());
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::setSpeed(int s)
{
    speed = s;
}

int WidgetMarqueeLabel::getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::setDirection(int d)
{
    direction = d;
    if (direction==RightToLeft)
        px = width() - textLength;
    else
        px = 0;
    refreshLabel();
}

void WidgetMarqueeLabel::close()
{
        QLabel::close();
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to make the text reappear before the text that reaches the end of the last letter on the right. I want something like this: for example (white space are 25):

```
WidgetMarqueeLabel
tMarqueeLabel                         Widge
eLabel                         WidgetMarque
el                          WidgetMarqueeLa
                      WidgetMarqueeLabel
               WidgetMarqueeLabel
       WidgetMarqueeLabel
WidgetMarqueeLabel
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm assuming the second line in your example output is mistaken--it doesn't seem to fit the pattern.

Answer (score 14):

For this purpose, I once wrote a class.

> [image]
>   *Example screenshot showing the text "This is an example text. It will be scrolled horizontally.". Note the alpha blending at both sides.*

### The code:

**scrolltext.h:**

```
#ifndef SCROLLTEXT_H
#define SCROLLTEXT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStaticText>
#include <QTimer>


class ScrollText : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString separator READ separator WRITE setSeparator)

public:
    explicit ScrollText(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    QString text() const;
    void setText(QString text);

    QString separator() const;
    void setSeparator(QString separator);


protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

private:
    void updateText();
    QString _text;
    QString _separator;
    QStaticText staticText;
    int singleTextWidth;
    QSize wholeTextSize;
    int leftMargin;
    bool scrollEnabled;
    int scrollPos;
    QImage alphaChannel;
    QImage buffer;
    QTimer timer;

private slots:
    virtual void timer_timeout();
};

#endif // SCROLLTEXT_H
```

**scrolltext.cpp:**

```
#include "scrolltext.h"
#include <QPainter>


ScrollText::ScrollText(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent), scrollPos(0)
{
    staticText.setTextFormat(Qt::PlainText);

    setFixedHeight(fontMetrics().height());
    leftMargin = height() / 3;

    setSeparator("   ---   ");

    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_timeout()));
    timer.setInterval(50);
}

QString ScrollText::text() const
{
    return _text;
}

void ScrollText::setText(QString text)
{
    _text = text;
    updateText();
    update();
}

QString ScrollText::separator() const
{
    return _separator;
}

void ScrollText::setSeparator(QString separator)
{
    _separator = separator;
    updateText();
    update();
}

void ScrollText::updateText()
{
    timer.stop();

    singleTextWidth = fontMetrics().width(_text);
    scrollEnabled = (singleTextWidth > width() - leftMargin);

    if(scrollEnabled)
    {
        scrollPos = -64;
        staticText.setText(_text + _separator);
        timer.start();
    }
    else
        staticText.setText(_text);

    staticText.prepare(QTransform(), font());
    wholeTextSize = QSize(fontMetrics().width(staticText.text()), fontMetrics().height());
}

void ScrollText::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);

    if(scrollEnabled)
    {
        buffer.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
        QPainter pb(&buffer);
        pb.setPen(p.pen());
        pb.setFont(p.font());

        int x = qMin(-scrollPos, 0) + leftMargin;
        while(x < width())
        {
            pb.drawStaticText(QPointF(x, (height() - wholeTextSize.height()) / 2) + QPoint(2, 2), staticText);
            x += wholeTextSize.width();
        }

        //Apply Alpha Channel
        pb.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
        pb.setClipRect(width() - 15, 0, 15, height());
        pb.drawImage(0, 0, alphaChannel);
        pb.setClipRect(0, 0, 15, height());
        //initial situation: don't apply alpha channel in the left half of the image at all; apply it more and more until scrollPos gets positive
        if(scrollPos < 0)
            pb.setOpacity((qreal)(qMax(-8, scrollPos) + 8) / 8.0);
        pb.drawImage(0, 0, alphaChannel);

        //pb.end();
        p.drawImage(0, 0, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        p.drawStaticText(QPointF(leftMargin, (height() - wholeTextSize.height()) / 2), staticText);
    }
}

void ScrollText::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)
{
    //When the widget is resized, we need to update the alpha channel.

    alphaChannel = QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    buffer = QImage(size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

    //Create Alpha Channel:
    if(width() > 64)
    {
        //create first scanline
        QRgb* scanline1 = (QRgb*)alphaChannel.scanLine(0);
        for(int x = 1; x < 16; ++x)
            scanline1[x - 1] = scanline1[width() - x] = qRgba(0, 0, 0, x << 4);
        for(int x = 15; x < width() - 15; ++x)
            scanline1[x] = qRgb(0, 0, 0);
        //copy scanline to the other ones
        for(int y = 1; y < height(); ++y)
            memcpy(alphaChannel.scanLine(y), (uchar*)scanline1, width() * 4);
    }
    else
        alphaChannel.fill(qRgb(0, 0, 0));


    //Update scrolling state
    bool newScrollEnabled = (singleTextWidth > width() - leftMargin);
    if(newScrollEnabled != scrollEnabled)
        updateText();
}

void ScrollText::timer_timeout()
{
    scrollPos = (scrollPos + 2)
                % wholeTextSize.width();
    update();
}
```

Comment: good job, I am using your class to draw text on a QvideoWidget, I am having 2 problems, I cant change the color of the text to white, and I cant make the ScrollText background to be invisible, it is showing a black box

Comment: well, I could change the text color now, but the widget is not updating itself properly, it does not erase the previous draw when it is used in front of the video widget

Comment: @fredcrs I'm sorry but I don't know how to solve this problem. This is a general problem of having a transparent, animated widget over another widget. I'd guess that the widget below has to update the region covered by the widget above in order to solve this problem.

Comment: I had to use a black background, I think that QVideoWidget is not repaiting itself, nor does use the repaint() method to repaint itself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @leemes This is cool. I have a existing UI form with some labels but how can i add this code to my project to see the scrolling effect? because I'm new to Qt and C++.

Comment: Very good cde! Only one issue, some text offset when need/no need to have scrolling. It happens due exptra QPoint(2, 2) in drawStaticText invoking. So QPoint(2, 2) should be remove from first case or added to the next.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've used it as the base of my PyQt5 implementation, fixing the issue with the uninitialized QImages (containing random data) and adding nice things like a pause each time the label has scrolled in its entirety. https://gist.github.com/ripdog/fc9db57d2c7c043d42577ef39e952db6

Answer (score 1):

Really easy. Simply repaint the text displaced by the width of the control:

```
void WidgetMarqueeLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *evt)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    if(direction==RightToLeft)
    {
        px -= speed;
        if(px <= (-textLength))
            px = width();
    }
    else
    {
        px += speed;
        if(px >= width())
            px = - textLength;
    }
    p.drawText(px, py+fontPointSize, text());
    __p.drawText(px-width(), py+fontPointSize, text());
    p.drawText(px+width(), py+fontPointSize, text());
    p.translate(px,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work. The padding is hard-coded at 25, which is what is sounded like you wanted. If you wanted the label to always be a certain size, you could use something like `QString::leftJustified`.

```
class MarqueeLabel : public QLabel {
 public:
  explicit MarqueeLabel(const QString &text) : QLabel(text), pos_(0) {
    QString pad(25, ' ');
    actual_text_ = text + pad;
    startTimer(100);
  }

protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) {
    pos_ = ++pos_ % actual_text_.length();
    setText(actual_text_.mid(pos_).append(actual_text_.left(pos_)));
  }

private:
  QString actual_text_;
  int pos_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MarqueeLabel lbl("WidgetMarqueeLabel");
    lbl.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```