# QTextEdit display width vs text width

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qfontmetrics

I'm creating a 'scrolling-text' class in Qt, using a `QTextEdit` (read-only, no scrollbars, moveCursor) and a `QTimer` - simple and working.

My problem is when the text sent to the class is shorter (narrower) than the QTextEdit-box.
Silly, I agree, but, being new to Qt, I didn't find an easy way to compare the width of the given text (depending on the font) and the actual width that can be displayed inside the `QTextEdit` (after calculating the FrameStyle, etc.). I presume I need to calculate the pixels.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you only want to display some text? Then a `QLabel` would be the better solution. I wrote a class to display a scrolling text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651514/text-scrolling-in-qlabel/10655396#10655396

Answer (score 2):

You can get the width of a text using `QFontMetrics`:

```
int textWidth = myTextEdit->fontMetrics().width(myTextEdit->text());
```

Comment: Problem is, if you have multiple lines, all of them get factored into the width instead of just the longest line